# How do I check if a string only has letters from a list of letters in Python

Tags: python, string, list, compare

word represents the string I am checking, letters is a list of random letters. I need to make sure that the word only contains letters in a list. However if their are repeating letters, there needs to be that many repeating letters in the list. If returned True it needs to remove the letters used in the word from the list. I am really struggling with this one.

```
example: w.wordcheck('feed') -> False
letters = ['n', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'e', 'a', 'z']
w.wordcheck('gag') -> false

w.wordcheck('gene')  -> True

w.wordcheck('gene') -> True
print(letters) -> ['f', 'a', 'z']



letters = []
def wordcheck(self, word)
    for char in word:
        if char not in self.letters:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1):

One way using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

letters = ['n', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'e', 'a', 'z']
cnt = Counter(letters)

def wordcheck(word):
    return all(cnt[k] - v >= 0 for k, v in Counter(word).items())
```

Output:

```
wordcheck("gag")
# False

wordcheck("gene")
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already better answers, but I felt like adding a novel solution just for the heck of it:

```py
from itertools import groupby


def chunks(s):
    return set("".join(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(s)))


def wordcheck(word, valid_letters):
    return chunks(word) <= chunks(valid_letters)
```

Steps:

1. Turn `word` into a set of chunks, e.g.: `"gag" -> {"a", "gg"}`
2. Turn `valid_letters` into a set of chunks
3. Check if `word` is a subset of `valid_letters`

Limitations:

1. This is a mostly silly implementation
2. This will only return `True` if the exact number of repeated letters is present in `valid_letters`, e.g.: if `valid_letters = "ccc"` and `word = "cc"` this will return `False` because there are too few `c`'s in `word`
3. It's really inefficient

Answer (score 0):

You can do solve , this problem by finding the case where word result into false.
these cases are, when the character is not in the letters and character frequency in word is more than the character frequency in the letter.

once if any of condition meet, return false else return true.

```
# your code goes here
from collections import Counter

letters = ['n', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'e', 'a', 'z']
letters_count = Counter(letters)


def func(word):
    word_count = Counter(word)
    check = True
    for word in word_count:
        if word not in letters_count or word_count.get(word)>letters_count.get(word):
            check = False
            break
    return check

l = ['feed', 'gag', 'gene']
for i in l:
    print(func(i))
```

output

```
False
False
True
```

Comment: How would I go about removing the letters used from the list? For each letter in the word it needs to remove the letter from the list. (if statement is true)

Comment: if you want to remove the letters and keep them removed from matched on then, befor return statement we need to remove the character suing `del` from the list